# Output each n-row + IFERROR in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to **organize a data array** using a single formula so that the output is a table like the sample to the right of the array (done manually)? Criteria:

1. Output every 14th row from column A
2. If there is an error, then extract all numbers from the cell with the error (there is a formula inside)

File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cjbvCyQaW2XL9dXb9RQSVOdJBG8alrqbrFc4r-XueLQ/edit#gid=0
[image]

Comment: Your example doesnt really match with your criteria the way they are currently written. I'd consider re-working your example and wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Λ,map(A:A,lambda(Σ,if(iserror(Σ),substitute(formulatext(Σ),"=+",),Σ))),
     tocol(choosecols(wraprows(Λ,14),14),3))
```

[image]